# Do electromagnetic fields also have thermal fluctuations?

Tags: electromagnetism

As far as I know electromagnetic fields have vacuum fluctuations. But can electromagnetic fields also have thermal fluctuations and can they induce current in coils? If the answers are positive. How does one model a fluctuating electromagnetic field inside the core of coil and its induced current. Could one model this as an ideal coil with a parallel fluctuating current source?

Comment: People trying to understand the thermodynamics of electromagnetic fields is basically what prompted the discovery of quantum mechanics. The fact that light is actually made of discrete particles, photons, has a big effect on the emission spectrum of a blackbody (for instance a kiln) at high frequencies of light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only *can* this happen, but what you are describing is essentially why you hear static on your radio or see it on your TV.

Thermal radiation (eg from the sun) follows a [blackbody spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). Thermal radiation can interact with a [resonant circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit) consisting of an inductor (coil), as well as a capacitor, tuned to amplify a certain frequency. Since the phase of the thermal radiation is random, any signal coming out of this circuit will be noisy. You can model this as a random current in the circuit.